# How do you say "which each" or "who each"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, relative-clauses

I speak in Persian, sometimes as I translate a sentence from my native language to English, I doubt if its structure is correct.

I want to say (for example)

"I have some children **who each** have a responsibility".

"There are some objects **which each** does something"..

Are they grammatical sentences? what should I say instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both *who each* and *which each* are acceptable, though be wary of verb agreement:

> I met three sisters who each have identical twins.
>
> The substance is regulated by the US and the EU, which each specify different toxicity levels.

In this case, we require plural agreement, *…objects which each do something* to be grammatical.

As Kevin notes, however, this construction may sound awkward; rephrasing your examples to say *each of whom* and *each of which* would be more natural. In that case the verb is singular for example *"there are some objects each of which does..."*

Comment: In AmE, I haven't heard anyone other than English teachers and the incurably pompous use the word *whom* in years.  I think that Ahmad's version, *who each* would be more likely.  That's only my opinion, mind you.

Comment: @JasonPatterson In certain phrases, *whom* certainly persists in AmE. You can say *Who are you talking to?* or write *To whom are you talking?* but *To who are you talking?* doesn't have much currency. SImilarly, *who each* or *each of whom*, and [there is absolutely no contest](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=each+of+who%2Ceach+of+whom&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3) between *each of whom* and *each of who*.

Comment: Absolutely, I wouldn't, and didn't, suggest *each of who.*

Comment: You say *each* needs **singular** verb, and I should use *do* !!, isn't *does* singular??

Comment: @Ahmad How embarassing! I apologize. *Do* is indeed plural, and it is the *plural* is conventional here, whereas it is always singular in *each of* constructions. Thus, *objects which each do* or *objects, each of which does*.

Comment: For what it's worth there's (at least) another option: "I met three sisters, each having identical twins", and "regulated by the US and the EU, each specifying different levels". In this case, though, the first of those is humorously ambiguous. I might mean they were in the process of delivering the twins as I met them ;-) This is by comparison with, "I met three three sisters, each having a coffee break".

Answer (score 4):

I would phrase them in the following way:

> I have some children, each of whom has a responsibility.
>
> There are some objects, each of which does something.

Alternatively, and perhaps more naturally,

> Each of my children has a responsibility.
>
> Each of these objects does something.

I would probably phrase them in the latter way, but the former construction is also valid (perhaps someone could correct my comma usage, but beyond that, it works).

Comment: How about "There are some objects. Each does something ..."? or "I have three children. Each has ..."? Do you mean this?